# Как получить двоичное значение SDDL ПРИГОДНОЕ ДЛЯ ЗАПИСИ В РЕЕСТР?

Tags: c#, безопасность, binary, службы

Пытаюсь получить дескриптор безопасности службы в двоичном виде, чтобы записать его в поле Security другой службы в реестре. Однако способы, представленные в интернете (с помощью PowerShell и C#) все как один возвращают не то двоичное значение, которое записано в реестре в поле Security соответствующей службы.

Например, есть некая служба, к которой в реестре уже записано поле Security. Я с помощью `sc sdshow <имя_службы>` получаю её дескриптор безопасности в строковом формате. Создаю из этой строки объект класса `RawSecurityDescriptor` в C#, после чего использую метод `GetBinaryForm`, возвращающий (по идее) как раз то, что мне нужно, а именно – тот же дескриптор в двоичном виде. Сравниваю полученный результат с тем, что записано в поле Security для рассматриваемой службы. И **значения не совпадают**! Если быть совсем уж точным, они совпадают частично, но не полностью.

Код того, что я делал:

```cpp
var rawSd = new RawSecurityDescriptor("D:(A;;CCLCSWRPLOCRRC;;;WD)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLORC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)");
_bytes = new byte[rawSd.BinaryLength];
rawSd.GetBinaryForm(_bytes, 0);
```

В переменной `_bytes` получается значение байтов (16ичные) типа:

```
0x01 0x00 0x04 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x14 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x70 ...
```

и так далее, их много.

В реестре же записаны значения с **другим началом (48 значениий) и другим концом (24 значения), но такой же серединой (всего значений около 200)**.

После тщательного рассмотрения записей в реестре выяснил, что концовка у всех значений поля Security (у разных служб) одинаковая. Для каждой службы одни и те же 24 байта. (все не проверял, но по крайней мере для многих это точно актуально).

Что ещё интереснее, в таком коде

```cpp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace TryingServicePermissions
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\audiosrv\Security");
            byte[] registryBytes = (byte[])key.GetValue("Security");
            RawSecurityDescriptor registryDecriptor = new RawSecurityDescriptor(registryBytes, 0);
            string registrySddl = registryDecriptor.GetSddlForm(AccessControlSections.All);
            Console.WriteLine($"SSDL from registry: {registrySddl}");

            RawSecurityDescriptor stringDecriptor = new RawSecurityDescriptor(registrySddl);
            byte[] _bytes = new byte[stringDecriptor.BinaryLength];
            stringDecriptor.GetBinaryForm(_bytes, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", _bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))));
        }
    }
}
```

после его выполнения значения переменных `registryBytes` и `_bytes` не равны! Хотя, логически рассуждая, я просто сделал из байтов строку и обратно.

И ещё одно добавление: если представленный выше блок кода дополнить таким строками

```cpp
RawSecurityDescriptor byteDecriptor = new RawSecurityDescriptor(_bytes, 0);
            if (registrySddl == byteDecriptor.GetSddlForm(AccessControlSections.All))
                Console.WriteLine("Equal!");
```

оно-таки выдаёт `Equal!`. То есть, не смотря на различные байтовые значения, строка разрешений всё же остаётся неизменной.

Вопрос: почему происходит вышеописанное и как всё-таки получить корректное двоичное представление дескриптора безопасности?

Comment: Код лучше тысячи слов :) И примеры значений тоже было бы хорошо увидеть.

Comment: @defaultlocale, код сейчас добавлю, хотя он предельно прост и я его по сути словами описал. Насчёт значений сложнее. Во-первых длинные, во-вторых из двоичных параметров реестра оно по-человечески не копируется

Comment: Попробуйте, интересно посмотреть.

Comment: @defaultlocale попробовал, смотрите

Comment: Хмм, судя по всему `sc sdshow` не включает компоненты вида `(D:` (SDDL_ACCESS_DENIED). Теперь осталось понять почему.

Comment: Вопрос: а почему бы изначально не прочитать нужное значение из реестра? зачем `sc sdshow`?

Comment: @defaultlocale вообще конечная цель – самому задавать дескриптор в строковом виде и с помощью программы прописывать всё это в реестр (уже в двоичном). То есть хочу научиться правильно конвертировать это. А что за компоненты `(D: (SDDL_ACCESS_DENIED)`?

Comment: Я просто сконвертировал значение из реестра обратно в SDDL и сравнил строки. Попробуйте тоже, возможно получите нужный формат: https://gist.github.com/defaultlocale/52d8330471de83f7a06382c6d913bbab Похоже что `sdshow` возвращает его в сжатом, удобочитаемом виде.

Comment: @defaultlocale Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @defaultlocale к сожалению, при конвертации результата работы Вашего кода обратно в двоичный формат, результат снова не совпал со значением Security в реестре. Я вообще сомневаюсь что поле Security содержит только дескриптор безопасности, но никак не могу найти, что в нём есть ещё

Comment: Странно. В моем коде `registryBytes` это как раз и есть двойчное значение.

Comment: @defaultlocale действительно, я только сейчас понял что это бессмысленно. Перепроверю ещё раз

Comment: @defaultlocale дополнил свой вопрос кодом, либо я чего-то не понимаю, либо конвертация какая-то необратимая получается

Comment: Интересно, при конвертации теряется что-то. Пока не знаю что.

Comment: @defaultlocale ещё дополнил

Comment: В общем пока не нашел я документации по формату Security в реестре. Судя по всему, официально поддерживается работа через Win32 и производные (sc, powershell), а не напрямую. Позже можно будет поискать исходники `RawSecurityDescriptor` посмотреть что он там меняет. Но пока я в тупике. Надо ждать как кто-нибудь более умный придет :)

Comment: Если нет цели писать в реестр напрямую, то можно поэкспериментировать с [`QueryServiceObjectSecurity`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-queryserviceobjectsecurity) и [`SetServiceObjectSecurity`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-setserviceobjectsecurity)

Comment: @defaultlocale Тем не менее, большое спасибо. Теперь я ближе к ответу.